# Removing headers from a PDF document using Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a dictionary in PDF format, where I need to remove a horizontal line at the top of the page with the words above it indicating the alphabetic range of words on the page, as shown on this picture
[image]

I am editing the document in Microsoft Word 2013, and it doesn't recognize the header
*as* a header -- it's just some text (and a line) that happens to be at the top of every page.
I don't know how I could remove this portion of the text from each page of the dictionary I have.

Comment: How *is* it formatted? It looks well done...I'm having trouble understanding how something that looks that good could have not used headers.

Comment: Hi Kazark! It is a pdf document opened in Word 2013 and the headings appear formatted the same as the rest of text, not as a header. It does look fine, but I need to remove the horizontal line and the text above from each page because I want to retain only the entries and their content, to be able to delimit it in Excel. I was wondering if there's a macro that can be used to cut off the top portion of text on every page, or maybe some other method to do this.

Comment: Is it still a PDF or have you converted it to Word format? If the latter, do you still have the original PDF?

Comment: I have the original PDF, I just opened it in Word. I didn't convert it, Word 2013 opens PDF very well, and the formatting remains more or less unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original PDF, the easiest solution may be to crop the top of the pages using a tool like [PDF-XchangeViewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (that's the one I use) or  you can use (of course) Adobe Acrobat or a search for "crop PDF" will turn up a lot of alternatives (e.g., Nitro, PDFill, etc.) But since my experience is with PDF-XchangeViewer, I'll explain how to do it there.

1. In the menu, select Document --> Crop Pages...
2. You'll get this dialog box
   [image: Crop Dialog]
3. Enter a value in the Top field that eliminates the header. You can see where the crop line will be in the preview on the right.
4. Press OK
5. Save the file with a new name

Note that this feature (cropping) is considered a Pro feature - so when you save the file it will add watermarks, if you have not purchased the Pro version. Personally, I think the Pro version is worth it. An alternative is to print to PDF using, e.g., [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator), and the watermarks will not appear in the output file.

Comment: Thank you for the idea yosh! I'll have to check PDF solutions to cut this part out of the dictionary if no one comes up with a Word solution for this.

Comment: Good luck - let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks yosh, I followed your advice and looked on the internet for PDF tools to do it, and I found a perfect one, and it's free to use. It is a Java application called PDF scissors, it worked perfectly, you may want to check it out.